# dont work MultiView and view control when upload project in host

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, upload, multiview

This code is correct in visual studio

But when upload in host and click on Button Error is displayed.

> Login failed for user 'WIN-1JU0K094NDD\IWPD_334(loyaltoi)'.
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed
>   for user 'WIN-1JU0K094NDD\IWPD_334(loyaltoi)'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

client code

```
            <asp:MultiView ID="mvShowListUsers" runat="server" ActiveViewIndex="0">
                <asp:View ID="VwShowUsers" runat="server">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-3">

                            <asp:Button ID="btnAddUser" runat="server" Text="add" CssClass="btn btn-warning" OnClick="btnAddUser_Click" />
                        </div>
```

connection string :

```
connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.;initial catalog=loyaltoi_CustomerDB;User ID=loyaltoi_CustomerDB1;Password=*****;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Comment: "The code is correct in Visual Studio". It may well be, but the error clearly states that SQL Server is rejecting the connection, either because the user/password is wrong, or because the user isn't allowed to access the SQL Server from the IP address the server is accessing it from.

Comment: @john 
I'm logged in correctly with this connection string

Comment: So from the same IP address as the server the ASP.NET site is running on, that connection string is working outside of the ASP.NET site?

Answer (score 0):

user or password for login database on host is wrong, or IP Address Database is wrong.
replace Dot (.) by ip addreess of database in "data source=. " connection string and cehck again user ID and password in connection string

Comment: I have no problem logging in. Only the MultiView control during the run has errors. please check my website .go to http://loyalto.ir/login.aspx and set user:aa & pass:1234 and click yellow btn

Comment: maybe Use an already existing login and set is as the user in your Application Pool. Check that the connection you want to open is not already open